# Magnifying Tiles in OpenLayers 2 or Increasing MaxZoom Without Distorting Projection

Tags: javascript, openlayers, bing-maps

I am using OpenLayers2 with Bing. My customer requires a deeper zoom level to interact with the maps. Currently, the max zoom level I can achieve is 19 which I tested with the getZoom() function. I have tried to set the "numZoomLevels" in the map constructor to a higher number, but Bing/OL just seems to ignore it. I was wondering if there is a way to force the tiles to a lower zoom level or if I could simply magnify the existing tiles so that I can see larger images even if the details are a bit blurry. It is crucial, however, that I don't modify the projection because having correct lat/lon values is paramount to the customer's function.

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
    allOverlays: false,
    numZoomLevels: 20,
    controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({
            dragPanOptions: {
                enableKinetic: true
            }
        }),
        new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Zoom({
            zoomInId: "customZoomIn",
            zoomOutId: "customZoomOut"
        })
    ]});

var aerial = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
    name: "Aerial",
    key: apiKey,
    type: "Aerial"
});
```

I did stumble across an OL3 [magnify example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/magnify.html), but it is written for OL3 and a bit beyond what I can convert since I need the magnify option to be embedded as a zoom level, not just a context overlay. Also, I don't have a ton of experience with canvas. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, and it's actually quite simple. First, the `numZoomLevels` should have been on the layer level, not the map level. If you want to be able to zoom in beyond what Bing provides you, you must set `fractionalZoom` to true as shown below:

```
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
    allOverlays: false,
    fractionalZoom: true,
    controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({
            dragPanOptions: {
                enableKinetic: true
            }
        }),
        new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Zoom({
            zoomInId: "customZoomIn",
            zoomOutId: "customZoomOut"
        })
    ]});
```

Then, on each layer, you need to set an array of resolutions. You will need to create a value for each zoom level you list under your `numZoomLevels`. I needed 22 zoom levels.

```
    var aerial = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
      name: "Aerial",
      key: apiKey,
      type: "Aerial",
      numZoomLevels: 22,
      resolutions: bingResolutions,
      serverResolutions: bingServerResolutions,
      transitionEffect: 'resize'
    });
```

In the source code for OpenLayers.Layer.Bing already had a resolution block defined which maps to their values at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa940990.aspx

```
var bingResolutions = [156543.03390625, 78271.516953125, 39135.7584765625,
19567.87923828125, 9783.939619140625, 4891.9698095703125,
2445.9849047851562, 1222.9924523925781, 611.4962261962891,
305.74811309814453, 152.87405654907226, 76.43702827453613,
38.218514137268066, 19.109257068634033, 9.554628534317017,
4.777314267158508, 2.388657133579254, 1.194328566789627,
0.5971642833948135, 0.29858214169740677, 0.14929107084870338,
0.07464553542435169];

var bingServerResolutions = [156543.03390625, 78271.516953125, 39135.7584765625,
19567.87923828125, 9783.939619140625, 4891.9698095703125,
2445.9849047851562, 1222.9924523925781, 611.4962261962891,
305.74811309814453, 152.87405654907226, 76.43702827453613,
38.218514137268066, 19.109257068634033, 9.554628534317017,
4.777314267158508, 2.388657133579254, 1.194328566789627,
0.5971642833948135];
```

The server resolutions are the tile resolutions from Bing itself. The additional resolutions `(0.29858214169740677, 0.14929107084870338, 0.07464553542435169)` are my fractional zoom levels that just zoom in on the layer 19 tile.

[Here](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/clientzoom.js) is the working example from OpenLayers for an OSM layer.

Hope this helps someone else!